# What Typescript type is a change event? (In Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to figure out what Typescript type a change event is used in an Angular project.

The code is something simple like this:

**file-upload.component.html**

```html
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
```

**file-upload.ts**

```
public onChange(event: Event): void {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    console.log(file);
  }
}
```

Typing the event as `Event` gives me the following Typescript linting error:

```
Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'
```

What should I be typing this if not `Event`?

Comment: You need to investigate about [(ngModel)] to get the reference of the input

Comment: I think you're looking for to get your event.target is `(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value` instead and `Event` is correct considering that's the [correct interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#events-2) for `change` technically, but can't test at the moment so just a comment.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It is an event. But you're going to have to cast the const you're using as an HTMLInputElement.

```
public onChange(event: Event): void {
  if ((event.target as HTMLInputElement).files && (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files.length) {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
  }
}
```

The only other way is going to be to suppress the error with tsignore. In react, flow, they have a type SyntheticEvent that you can type this particular case as to get around it but angular doesn't have a real equivalent.

Comment: This does work to get rid of that TS error, but has a problem with on line 3: `Type 'FileList' is not an array type` @qt-ray

Comment: Would you be able to wrap the event.target in line three as HTMLInputElement and use `const files = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files` and get the file you need? I can help more wit that if you'd like as well!

Answer (score 23):

```
public onChange(event: Event): void {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    if (!input.files?.length) {
        return;
    }

    const file = input.files[0];
    console.log(file);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You just have to write this before doing anything with your event:

```
if (!(event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement)) return;
```

Typescript will then know that your `event.target` is an instance of `HTMLInputElement` and it will stop yelling at you.

Answer (score 8):

You could specify property `target` of `Event` to be an `HTMLInputElement` using an intersection type as the typehint of `event`.

```
public onChange(event: Event & { target: HTMLInputElement }): void {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    console.log(file);
  }
}
```

> An intersection type combines multiple types into one. This allows you to add together existing types to get a single type that has all the features you need.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types

Comment: nice trick, but here you get a compile error in the html-template: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Event & { target: HTMLInputElement; }'.

Comment: Right, I've tested this on Vue 2.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution for Angular. No Compile error here on the template with Angular 14

Answer (score 6):

If you're **Typescript** with **React** user and landed on this thread like I did, this will work for you:

```
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { 
   // do something 
}
```

Comment: "Angular" is in the title of the question

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer throws two errors in my compiler: `(event.target as HTMLInputElement).files is possibly 'null'` and `Type 'FileList' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator`.

This works for me:

```
const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

if (target.files && target.files.length) {
  const file = target.files[0];
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most elegant way to do this, especially if you're reusing this pattern, you can just name `target` something more distinct and then export it at the app level. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the files should be a accessible thru the `event.srcElement.files` property.

Comment: This gives me a similar TS linting error
`Property 'files' does not exist on type 'Element'.`